# Save document in PHP simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom, save, overwrite, simple-html-dom

I have a problem with PHP simple HTML DOM.

The following to save the code in a text document ...

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$a= file_get_html('http://web.com');
$a->save('text.txt');
?>
```

But only the first time creates it, if I try to update it appears not to overwrite

What could be the problem?

EDIT: the text file that is created is not updated when I run the PHP.

The website does change.

Comment: it is not clear what are you asking

Comment: the text file that is created is not updated when I run the PHP.

Comment: but did "http ://web.com" change meanwhile? if not why shoud the text.txt change

Comment: of course. What is your referal point? your browser? take in mind that browsers manage at least cookies (and frames, and so on) in order to see diferent responses from the same url. but simple_html_dom does? i do not remember. have you configured it in that way? I suggest curl for this job, if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why use simplehtmldom for this? It's massive overhead just to write out a file.

```
<?php
    file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('http://web.com'));
```

would accomplish the same thing

Comment: It is incompatible with the code that try to keep ... gives a warning

Comment: try to keep what? and what warning?

Comment: He shows me part of the code of the website and the warning. But does not say exactly what the problem is

Comment: He? what is the warning text? A php warning? or something from the website itself?

Answer (score 0):

When you expect the output file to change, are you:

1. Reloading the *modified* webpage `$a = file_get_html('http://web.com');`
2. Modifying the object `$a` directly

If you are not doing 2), then as Marc B suggests, do not use simplehtmldom.
If you are doing 1), output `$a`, `var_dump($a);` as a first step to ensure that the object was actually modified.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is not changed becouse nothing else has also changed, in particular http ://web.com